# How to change the Block position or product view page design in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, product-page, up-sells, featured-product

I want to move (Upsell) bottom of the Product page. And How to move any block in Product page in Magento2.

Also How to add Feature Product before Upsell Product in Product page Magento2?

Comment: Do you have any readymade code so we can elaborate on how you can do this? otherwise, it is quite hard to share all the code and processes here.

Comment: Feel free to accept the answer if it helped

Answer (score 0):

in your theme create a file

> magentolocation/app/design/frontent/vendor/theme/Magento_Catalog/layout/catalog_product_view.xml

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <move element="product.info.upsell" destination="content" before="before.body.end"/>
    </body>
</page>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should identify the name of the block you want to move, and the destination

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/frontend-dev-guide/layouts/xml-instructions.html#fedg_layout_xml-instruc_ex_mv

In this case, you can start inspecting layout file **vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/layout/catalog_product_view.xml** (or the one in your theme, if you are using a frontend theme)

I guess you will get all info you need there, for instance

```
<block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Upsell" name="product.info.upsell" template="Magento_Catalog::product/list/items.phtml">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="type" xsi:type="string">upsell</argument>
        <argument name="view_model" xsi:type="object">Magento\Catalog\ViewModel\Product\Listing\PreparePostData</argument>
    </arguments>
    <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Item\Container" name="upsell.product.addto" as="addto">
        <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Item\AddTo\Compare"
               name="upsell.product.addto.compare" as="compare"
               template="Magento_Catalog::product/list/addto/compare.phtml"/>
    </block>
</block>
```